# store strings in stable memory in c++

Tags: c++

A little bit of background first (skip ahead to the boldface if you're bored by this).

I'm trying to glue two pieces of code together. One is a JSON/YML library that makes heavy use of a custom string view object, the other is a piece of code from the early 2000s.

I've been seeing weird behavior for a long time, until I have traced it down to a memory issue, namely that the string views I construct in the JSON/YML library take a `const char*` as a constructor, and assume that the memory location of that char array stays constant over the lifetime of the string view. However, some of the `std::string` objects on which I construct these views are temporary, so that's just not true and the string view ends up pointing at garbage.

Now, I thought I was being smart and constructed a cache in the form of a `std::vector` that would hold all the temporary strings, I would construct the string views on these and only clear the cache in the end - easy.

However, I was still seeing garbled strings every now and then, until I found the reason: sometimes, when pushing things to the vector beyond the preallocated size, the vector would be moved to a different memory location, invalidating all the string views. For now, I've settled on preallocating a cache size that is large enough to avoid any conceivable moving of the vector, but I can see this causing severe and untracable problems in the future for very large runs. So here's my question:

**How can I construct a `std::vector<std::string>` or any other string container that either avoids being moved in memory alltogether, or at least throws an error message if that happens?**

Of course, if you feel that I'm going about this whole issue in the wrong way fundamentally, please also let me know how I should deal with this issue instead.

If you're interested, the two pieces of code in question are RapidYAML and the CERN Statistics Library ROOT.

Comment: reserve enough space before filling the vector or check that begin() deliver the same iterator every time, if not, raise your error. Or use a data structure like list which will not move the data around

Comment: Using plain pointers, `const char*` instead of `std::string`, will keep the pointers stable. Although this will require manual allocation of the strings, and manual cleanup when destroying the vector.

Answer (score 2):

My answer from a similar question: [Any way to update pointer/reference value when vector changes capability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517909/any-way-to-update-pointer-reference-value-when-vector-changes-capability/58518170#58518170)

If you store objects in your vector as std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr, you can get an observing pointer to the underlying object with std::unique_ptr::get() (or a reference if you dereference the smart pointer). This way, even though the memory location of the smart pointer changes upon resizing, the observing pointer points to the same object and thus the same memory location.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] sometimes, when pushing things to the vector beyond the preallocated size, the vector would be moved to a different memory location, invalidating all the string views.

The reason is that `std::vector` is required to store its data contiguously in memory. So, if you exceed the maximum capacity of the vector when adding an element, it will allocate a new space in memory (big enough this time) and move all the data here.

What you are subject to is called **iterator invalidation**.

> How can I construct a std::vector or any other string container that either avoids being moved in memory alltogether, or at least throws an error message if that happens?

You have at least 3 easy solutions:

1. If your cache size is supposed to be fixed and is known at compile-time, I would advise you to use `std::array` instead.
2. If your cache size is supposed to be fixed but not necessarily known at compile-time, I would advise you to [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) the required capacity of your `std::vector` so that you will have the guarantee that it will big enough to not need to be reallocated.
3. If your cache size may change, I would advise you to use `std::list` instead. It is implemented as a (usually doubly) linked list. It will guarantee that the elements will not be relocated in memory.
   But since they are not stored contiguously in memory, you'll lose the ability to have direct access to any element (i.e. you'll need to iterate over the list in order to find an element).

Of course there probably are other solutions (I do not claim this answer to be exhaustive) but these solutions will allow you to almost not change your code (only the container) and protect your string views to be invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use an std::list. Its accessing method is slower (at least when iterating) but memory location is constant. Reason for both is that it does not use contiguous memory.

Alternatively create a wrapper that wraps a pointer to a string that has been created with "new". That address will also be constant. EDIT: Somehow I managed to miss that what I've just described is pretty much a smartpointer minus automated deletion ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well sadly it is impossible to be able to grow a vector while being sure the content will stay at the same place on classical OS at least.

There is the function [realloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) that tries to keep the same place, but as you can read on the documentation, there is no guarantee to that, only the os will decide.

To solution your problem, you need the concept of a [pool](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/memory-pool-allocators-with-jonathan-mueller), a pool of string here, that handle the life time of your strings.

You may get away with a simple `std::list` of string, but it will lead to bad data aliasing and a lot of independent allocations bad to your performances. These will also be the problems with smart pointers.

So if you care about performances, how you may implement it in your case may be not far from your current implementation in my opinion. Because you cannot resize the vector, you should prefer an `std::array` of a fixed size that you decide at compile time. Then, whenever you need it, you can create a new one to expand your memory capacity. This may be easily implemented by a `std::list<std::array>` typically.

I don't know if it applies here, but you must be careful if your application can create any number of string during its execution as it may induce an ever growing memory pool, and maybe finally memory problems. To fix that you may insure that the strings you don't use anymore can be reused or freed. Sadly I cannot help you too much here, as these rules will depend on your application.